# Method to get Rows in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Hey guys I'm new to Java and I would like to create a method to get all the rows of a given matrix.

I was able to do it and here's my code:

```
public void matrixRows(double[][] matrix)
{
    int row = matrix.length;
    int col = matrix[0].length;

    double[] firstRow = new double[row];
    double[] secondRow = new double[row];
    double[] thirdRow = new double[row];
    double[] fourthRow = new double[row];
    double[] fifthtRow = new double[row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                firstRow[i] = matrix[0][j];
            }

            else if (i == 1)
            {
                secondRow[i] = matrix[1][j];
            }
        }
    }


}
```

It works fine but I think there's a better solution. Thanks in advance! ^.^

Comment: Well, matrix is an array of rows. It contains all the rows: matrix[0] is the first row, matrix[1] is the second row, etc. Not sure what you're asking or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow.  It may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but please remember to check [their rules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting.

Comment: If you already have a working solution, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic might be more helpful - but do check their rules first.